# How to run TAP::Harness tests written in Guile?

Tags: unit-testing, guile

The usual approach of

```
test:
    $(PERL) "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness($(TEST_VERBOSE), '$(INCDIRS)')" $(TEST_FILES)
```

fails to run Guile scripts, because it passes to Guile the extra parameter "-w".

Comment: You probably want to split the answer out and post it as an actual answer, below. That will work better in terms of the site’s design.

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach is to set up your project as follows.

Your directory structure is as follows:

```
./project              Your project files
./project/t/*.t        Your unit test scripts
./project/t/scripts/*  Auxiliary scripts used by your unit tests
```

Your *./project/Makefile* contains the following:

```
PERL = /usr/bin/perl
TEST_LIBDIRS = ./lib
RUN_GUILE_TESTS = ./t/scripts/RunGuileTests.pl
TEST_FILES = ./t/*.t

test:
    $(PERL) -I$(TEST_LIBDIRS) $(RUN_GUILE_TESTS) $(TEST_FILES)
```

Your *./project/t/scripts/RunGuileTests.pl* contents are:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
# Run Guile tests - filenames are given as arguments to the script.

use TAP::Harness;
my @tests = @ARGV;
my %args = (
    verbosity => 0,
    timer => 1,
    show_count => 1,
    exec => ['/usr/bin/guile', '-s'],
    );
my $harness = TAP::Harness->new( \%args );
        $harness->runtests(@tests);

# End of RunGuileTests.pl
```

Your Guile test scripts should start with:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile -s
!#
; Description of your tests
```